# force download youtube videos from url in browser (client-site) in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api

I am working on youtube video downloader site that is using `node` based server-site. I am using `npm` package called `ytdl-core` and this module is returning download link. But, when I click on that link it redirects me to "video preview" instead of "trigger download",

```
ytdl(url, function(err, format) {
  if (err) {res.send('the url is invalid please try again...');}
  console.log((format.formats).length);//i am getting value... in console but not outside of the function.. 
  //this object contains all the download links  
  var links = []
  for( var i= 0, len = (format.formats).length; i < len; i++) {
    var el = format.formats[i].container;
    if ( el === 'mp4') {
      var download_url = format.formats[i];
      //this push will store the all links in 'links' object..
      links.push(download_url);
    }
  }
  console.log(links);
});
```

So when I paste the link into my browser, it redirects me to preview instead of trigger download. I am getting link that looks like this:

```
https://r8---sn-gxap5ojx-cage.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?upn=P6gEaXLtqOc&ei=ROrcWMzGKsjfoAPtl6XYAg&id=o-AIBZRxwo9AvJU4q02_xR0lfxJbSV3pxpga67Si4bLieu&key=yt6&ip=139.59.64.12&ipbits=0&pl=20&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=8882500&ratebypass=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&itag=18&expire=1490894500&mime=video%2Fmp4&pcm2cms=yes&source=youtube&mv=m&mt=1490872775&ms=au&lmt=1487309879666192&clen=8449602&gir=yes&mn=sn-gxap5ojx-cage&mm=31&dur=221.518&signature=6ED71F39CAA3B6719A8BAAEABD51D568ABF4D7A3.B3EED034140574BAC9733EC5CC28EF4AC9E3F758&title=Kygo Selena Gomez It Ain t Me with Selena Gomez Audio
```

My question is, how can I force download that video to client's browser by clicking button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express it may be helpful to use [res.download()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download). It would work along the lines of this.

```
res.download(downloadLink, downloadTitle, function(err){
  if (err) {
    // Handle error, but keep in mind the response may be partially-sent
    // so check res.headersSent
  } else {
    // decrement a download credit, etc.
  }
});
```

Good luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: yes , but i want to let users to download that video on their browser, and in this case the video download url is showing preview instead of trigger download...

Answer (score 0):

i have found very simple solution is that you need add attribute `"download='true'` into your html code! and it's look like this

```
<a href='yourdownloadlink.com/example' download='true'>force download!</a>
```